# WPF GridView Telerik - Application memory issue

Tags: wpf, gridview, telerik, telerik-grid

I have the following memory issue when sorting, filtering, grouping, pagging...:

I open the task manager for monitoring my app's memory, after load all data (like 500 records with 90 columns) the app's memory was like 150mb, then every time I repeat an action (I tried with reordering  with any column) the memory increase, increase, increase and **NEVER RELEASE**

I tried the same test case with examples, and after load some memory the GC free the unused one.

Plesae helps, I will apreciate any tips.

---

**Code**

```
<telerik:RadGridView Name="dataGrid" Margin="4" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Extended" AlternationCount="2" AlternateRowBackground="LightGray" FrozenColumnCount="{Binding FrozenColumnIndex}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"  view:GridViewHeaderMenu.IsEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <view:NumberColumn Header="#" Width="50" DataPager="{Binding ElementName=radDataPager1}" />
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col1" HeaderTextAlignment="Center" DataType="{x:Type System:String}"   DataMemberBinding="{Binding Value1}" view:GridColumnToolTip.TextTooltip="{Binding DataContext.ColumnsDescription.Value1ColumnTooltip, ElementName=userControl}"/>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col2" HeaderTextAlignment="Center" DataType="{x:Type System:Int32}"   DataMemberBinding="{Binding Value2}" view:GridColumnToolTip.TextTooltip="{Binding DataContext.ColumnsDescription.Value2ColumnTooltip, ElementName=userControl}"/>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col3" HeaderTextAlignment="Center" DataType="{x:Type System:Double}"   DataMemberBinding="{Binding Value3}" DataFormatString="N3" view:GridColumnToolTip.TextTooltip="{Binding DataContext.ColumnsDescription.Value3ColumnTooltip, ElementName=userControl}"/>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col Hide/Show Binding" HeaderTextAlignment="Center" DataType="{x:Type System:String}"   DataMemberBinding="{Binding Value4}" IsVisible="{Binding IsIndividual}" view:GridColumnToolTip.TextTooltip="{Binding DataContext.ColumnsDescription.Value4ColumnTooltip, ElementName=userControl}"/>
        <!--other 90 columns-->
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <telerik:RadDataPager x:Name="radDataPager1" PageSize="20"  DisplayMode="All" Source="{Binding Items, ElementName=dataGrid}"
        IsTotalItemCountFixed="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="8,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10.667"><Run Text="Ta"/><Run Language="es-es" Text="maño de página:"/></TextBlock>

    <telerik:RadNumericUpDown NumberDecimalDigits="0" Value="{Binding PageSize, ElementName=radDataPager1, Mode=TwoWay}" Minimum="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: 150 Mb is too much. Please post your code behind with the connection to database. However, 90 columns are really too many. Just for comparison, I get approx. 7 Mb with 20 columns.

Comment: @FeliceM I'm don't worry about the initial 150Mbs because relly are a lot of data, I'm worry about the memory that doesn't get release. If user interact to much with the grid the application can get 2GB of memory and more.

Comment: It seams that the GC doesn't get the memory as free